# 1/4 copper to 1/2 PEX to 1/4 copper?

Tags: plumbing, pex, copper

I have an old home that has a 1/4 copper line running from a copper valve tee in the basement, directly up through the floor boards, into the fridge.

I'm trying to add an ice maker valve box behind my fridge (to stop constant leaks when the fridge is moved).  The valve box I got accepts 1/2 PEX into it, and has a 1/4 compression fitting.

Can I use some sharkbite fittings to go from a stub of the existing 1/4 copper line, into 1/2 PEX, up to the valve box, then back to 1/4 copper/braided to connect the fridge?  Will I have enough pressure?

I'd definitely prefer not to mess with the good job someone did on the copper valve tee.

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't clear why presence of a valve would stop leaks -- it's hard to decide whether an answer should address how to incorporate the valve you picked, or whether it would be better to address the unasked question "the existing piping arrangement leaks when the fridge is moved; how could I fix that?"

Comment: At a minimum, a picture of the parts in question would help people understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Since a fridge doesn't draw much water,  feel free to use whatever PEX to pipe adapters you can find, attached to appropriate pipe-size adapters to get to the size copper you need. It doesn't have to be elegant, it just needs to be water-tight and fit in the available space.